# How to restrict the instantiation of a class based on the ancestry of the templated type

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++17, type-traits

I have a templated class `XX` and would like to restrict the instantiation of it to only types `T` that are descendants of another class `ZZ`:

```
class ZZ {
public:
    int transmorgificationFactor;
};

template <typename T>
class XX {
public:
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<ZZ, T>, "T must be a ZZ");
    T foo;
    // ...
};
```

Using Visual Studio 2019 C++ (ISO C++17) I am getting

> error C2275: 'std::is_base_of<ZZ, T>': illegal use of this type as an
> expression

Is this not the proper way to use `std::is_base_of<>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::is_base_of` is a type, which can't be used as a condition in `static_assert`. You're looking for `std::is_base_of_v` instead:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<ZZ, T>, "T must be a ZZ");
                          // ^^
```

or pre-C++17, you can do:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<ZZ, T>::value, "T must be a ZZ");
                                 // ^^^^^^^
```